# Управление проводником церез python

Tags: python, winapi, explorer

Здраствуйте, мне нужно узать как можно управлять проводником в системе "windows". Объясню на примерах:
Допустим у меня есть проект, с которым я не хочу делиться с другими пользователями это компьютера, я хочу чтобы программа проверяла путь к определённому(ой) файлу/папке, и в случае с папками чтобы дочерние папки тоже нельзя было попасть, точнее этот путь заменялся на начало диска, тоесть:
Пользователь зашёл в папку с моим проектом:
C:\папка\папка1\мой_проект.тхт
Но путь в котором пользователь находиться изменился на:
С:\ 
В случае с файлом, он просто сразу же закрывался
Это был всего лишь пример того что я хочу видеть от этого модуля или библиотеки.
Есть ли что - то, что может мне это обеспечить?

Comment: Есть более простые способы скрыть папку от других https://www.911-win.ru/article/kak-zaparolit-papku-na-kompyutere/

Comment: Это не имеет смысла, т.к. другой пользователь может скопировать весь ваш проект с помощью командной строки

Comment: Мне нужна эта информация для того, чтобы я просто научился управлять проводником через python

Comment: задумка ниочень. лучше в винде настроки доступа поковыряйтесь. если 'управлять'  то посмотрите модуль pyautogui